# Configure prestashop through theme configuration

Tags: configuration, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am wondering if it possible to configure some of the shop’s options when enabling a theme.

Let me explain, I am already generating a config.xml in the root of the theme zip to enable/disable some modules or hooks. But I want to do more.

Indeed, I would like to be able to, for example, enable the CCC “Move JavaScript to the end” when the theme.

I see that some themes ([including the community theme](https://github.com/PrestaShop/community-theme-16/blob/dev/themes/community-theme-16/config.xml)) include a `config.xml` inside the theme folder. I often see stuff like `<ccc available="true" />`.

But I’m not sure it does anything. Does it do anything?

I can’t find any reference for that config.xml file, is there any way to achieve what I want?

Using the latest Prestashop 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lines check configuration values but only when `<ccc available="false" />`.

So if you have `<ccc available="true" />` you are saying that your theme is `CCC` compatible and it doesn't matter if the shop has `CCC` enabled or not.

If you set that to `false`, the installation will check if settings related to `CCC` are disabled, otherwise it will throw an error to the user that their `CCC` configurations will not work with your theme.

You can see feature definitions [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/admin/AdminThemesController.php#L55).

```
    'ccc' => array(
        'attributes' => array(
            'available' => array(
                'value' => 'true',
                /*
                 * accepted attribute value if value doesn't match, prestashop configuration value must have those values
                */
                'check_if_not_valid' => array(
                    'PS_CSS_THEME_CACHE' => 0,
                    'PS_JS_THEME_CACHE' => 0,
                    'PS_HTML_THEME_COMPRESSION' => 0,
                    'PS_JS_HTML_THEME_COMPRESSION' => 0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'error' => 'This theme may not correctly use PrestaShop\'s "combine, compress and cache" options.',
        'tab' => 'AdminPerformance',
    )
```

So if you set in your `config.xml` `<ccc available="false" />` it will check that all four configurations in `check_if_not_valid` array are set to 0, otherwise it's gonna throw out an error message `This theme may not correctly use PrestaShop's "combine, compress and cache" options.`.

As for configuring settings on theme install, I don't see a way to do it with xml config without overriding `AdminThemesController` class but I'm guessing you want to distribute this theme so overriding is not an option.

What you could do though is install a simple configuration setter module along with the theme that hooks to [`displayAfterThemeInstallation`](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/admin-dev/themes/default/template/controllers/themes/helpers/view/view.tpl#L30).

```
public function hookDisplayAfterThemeInstallation($params)
{
    $theme_name = $params['theme_name'];
    if ($theme_name != 'mythemename') {
        return false;
    }
    // Enable Move JS to bottom setting
    Configuration::updateValue('PS_JS_DEFER', 1);

    // Optional text or html to display 
    return 'Your settings have been changed';
}
```

Comment: The community theme actually includes a theme that does similar things: https://github.com/PrestaShop/community-theme-16/blob/dev/modules/ctconfiguration/ctconfiguration.php

Comment: s/theme/module/ …